# Insert Items in list view without blocking UI Thread in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, listview

I have two threads that access the UI thread to do some operations,
first thread just show a loading image,
and the second thread populates a listview with a some itens.

My problem is when the listview is being populated it blocks the UI thread and the loading image stops.

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PopulateListView));
th.Start();

void PopulateListView()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ultraListView1.Items.Add("abc"+i)));
        }
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: This is one of the things that was changed in WPF. As others said, UI runs off a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

> What i'm doing wrong ??

You can only populate the UI from the main thread.  As soon as you do `Invoke`, you're pushing the work back onto the main (UI) thread.  This means that you will still block the UI, even if you start this from a separate thread.

There is no direct way around this.  If your data takes a long time to load, you can potentially *load* it on a background thread, but adding it to the `ListView` will always need to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: But he's not loading all of his items at once; he's only adding one item per `Invoke` call, so the loading form ought to be able to update between those calls.

Comment: @Servy True - but he is flooding the message pump with all of those calls, which are very "quick" calls, so there's not going to be any type of responsiveness in this.

Comment: If he used `BeginInvoke` then I'd agree, but as it is he'll never have more than 1 item in the message pump at a time, and each item individually shouldn't take long, so any items added to the message pump from elsewhere (i.e. the other background thread, the OS, etc.) should be handled reasonably quickly.  My guess is that either he's generating an item in some expensive way inside of `Invoke`, or there is in some other way code not shown causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a rush, so sorry if I'm whiffing this one.

1. Generate a worker thread to to perform the async operation. (which it looks like you've got handled.)  The [Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class may also be helpful. It has built in worker thread cancellation, and ProgressChanged event.
2. Every time a new chunk of data becomes available (a single entry, or if you'd prefer, a set of entries) raise an event passing the new data along.
3. In the event handler for the "announcement", push yourself to the GUI thread and add it to the control's data source.

This article has a nice explanation on checking your current thread, and invoking the GUI thread where necessary:

http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2007/02/simple-pattern-to-invoke-gui-from.html